# Android Job Scheduler not running with screen off

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I'm trying to make a background job that runs periodically and needs to connect to the network. I'm scheduling the job using the JobScheduler service in this way:

```
JobScheduler js = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

    if(js!=null) {
        if (js.getAllPendingJobs().size() == 0) {//No jobs scheduled in previous boots. Schedule one
            JobInfo.Builder b = new JobInfo.Builder(1, new ComponentName("my.app.name", MyJob.class.getName()));
            b.setPeriodic(420000);
            b.setPersisted(true);
            b.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);

            js.schedule(b.build());
        }
    }
```

The Job runs correctly when the screen is on, but as soon as it goes off it is not run anymore until it is turned on again (and then it starts immediately).
I'm guessing that it doesn't run because while the device is idle there is no network connection (even if I checked that the device Wi-Fi and 3G options say to keep connection active while idle).

How can I make my service run even when the device is idle/screen is off?

Comment: You may also be running into doze mode-  that's running ever 7 minutes, right?  When the phone dozes, you can't run more than once every 15, and will be pushed off until the phone decides to run you.  If dozing for a long period you may be run even less frequently.

Comment: Yes it was trying to run every 7 minutes. I didn't know about Doze mode, it could be the culprit. I'll test it for more time to see if the job eventually runs, but I already tested it for about half an hour and it hasn't run.

Comment: Regardless of doze mode, minimum periodic interval for the job scheduler is 15 minutes. See this post: stackoverflow.com/questions/48248172/

Comment: I changed the time to 15minutes now and I see that the Scheduled Job is now being executed correctly even with the screen off

Answer (score 0):

If your device is Huawei you can check the following [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/152649/what-is-protected-apps-in-huawei-phones) with protected apps.

Protected apps suspend apps when the screen is off.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not on a Huawei device :(